# Filling dataframe column with values from np.array

Tags: pandas, numpy, unique

I have a dataframe, and one column is labelled 'dist'. For each 'dist' value (array a), I calculated a metric that is stored in an array (b).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3,4,5], [4,4,4,4,4], [1,2,3,3,1]]),
               columns=['Id', 'size', 'dist'])

a = df['size'].unique(); 
a = np.array([1,2,3]);
b = np.array([10,9,8]);
```

Now, I want to add these b values (array b has smaller length that df) to my dataframe (df) and have the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3,4,5], [4,4,4,4,4], [1,2,3,3,1],[10,9,8,8,10]),
               columns=['Id', 'size', 'dist','b'])
```

Comment: Please **do not** use images of code/data, [edit] your answer with everything as **text**.

Comment: and post the code where you calculated mentioned metric

Comment: You can probably transform the np array into a dataframe, and then use the concatinate functionality (`pd.concat`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `c_[]`  to do this:

```
import numpy as np
a_array = [....] 
b_array = [....]

np.c_[a_array, b_array]
```

Docs: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html

Comment: But how can append the values from b array to the pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

So you can use np.c_[] as mentioned above but inside the dataframe creation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[[1, 2, 3,4,5], [4,4,4,4,4], [1,2,3,3,1]],
           columns=['Id', 'size', 'dist'])

b = [10,9,8,8,10]
# and adding newcolumn for b:
df["b"] = b
print(df)
```

This will create the output that you look for in your question.